# "Pitcher" or "Pitchee" when referring to oneself in a submission form

Tags: word-choice, professions

I'm pitching a story to a public broadcaster and the layout asks that I put my name on the top of the form. Am I the "Pitcher" or the "Pitchee", or should I just go with "Name"? "Name" seems too vague IMHO.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you are completing a form, why are you worried about using "Pitcher" or "Pitchee"? Just fill in what it asks for. What *does* it ask for?

Comment: Should I refer to myself as the "Pitcher" or "Pitchee" in the email? I don't believe "Pitchee" is even a word.

Comment: Without a link to the form it's not clear whether you're asking us **a)** what word *you* should use to label your name in your email or **b)** in which of three fields, labeled "Pitcher", "Pitchee" and "Name" you should identify yourself. If it's a), I have to ask Why do you feel you have to label your name at all?

Comment: I don't work in broadcasting, but I think any variant on *pitch* would be far too "slangy" for OP's intended context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix "-ee" comes from the French "é" which is used for the past participle of verbs in that language. For example, *données* the French word for data simply means "givens".

Since you are not pitched, *pitchee* would make no sense. If you pitch you are the agent i.e. the pitcher.

Answer (score 1):

You are the *pitcher*, if you want to go with that terminology. The -er suffix denotes the agent of the root verb, in this case "pitch." However, you could also call yourself the *[pitchman](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pitchman?s=t)* if you want to give the impression that you're a high-energy seller of ideas.